# Distinct projection query for ancestor/parent

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a "kind" that's constantly updated where the parent of the objects is an account. I'd like to get a list of distinct accounts from this table where the most recent object per account was inserted in the last 30 days.

It seems I can't use a projection query for the `parent` or ancestor. Here's essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
MyObject.query(default_options=QueryOptions(keys_only=True),projection=[MyObject.parent], 
                 distinct=True).filter(MyObject.creation_date>= start)
```

I end up with an error of:
`AttributeError: type object 'MyObject' has no attribute 'parent'`

Kind of expected, the model doesn't have a `parent`. A `key` has a parent.

Is there a way to do this? I understand projection queries are kind of like `SELECT` statements to get specific properties on an object but, this isn't sql as much as google might want to make it look like it is. I don't think this is that complicated of a query...

Answer (score 0):

To filter on the parent, one way would be to explicitly store the parent key in the model itself.

But even with that, the query you are trying to write is one of those aggregation queries that Datastore does not support:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent FROM MyObject WHERE creation_date >= ...
```

Datastore ensures queries scale with the number of results rather than the number of entities in the kind, and here there is no index that would give this guarantee.

1. if using an index on `parent, creation_date`, Datastore may need to examine a large number of `parent` before finding one where `creation_date > start`, so that scales with the number of entities in the kind.
2. if using an index on `creation_date, parent`, Datastore will need to skip over the rows of the index for `parent` that it has already seen, that also scales with the number of entities in the kind.

No silver bullet here, but you can do the aggregation separately. One approach would be to store a field on your model called `created_in_the_last_30_days`, that is initially set to `true`. You would need a (daily?) background job to flip that field from `true` to `false` for old entities, but then you can write your query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent FROM MyObject WHERE created_in_the_last_30_days = true
```

which would give you the expected results, ordered by `parent`.